# gnome-terminal not opening after library installation. ERROR: FT_Get_Var_Design_Coordinates

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lib

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and tried to install the Python version of Tecplot (Pytecplot), after which I'm unable to open the terminal anymore.

```
$ gnome-terminal 
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Design_Coordinates
```

My Bash_history shows following commands:

```
python3 setup.py  install
sudo python3 setup.py  install
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62:i386
sudo apt update sudo apt install libpng12-0
sudo cp libjpeg.so.62 ../
sudo cp libjpeg.so.62 ../../local/lib/
sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

I made a backup of `usr/local/lib` before starting, but restoring that backup did not solve the problem.

Can someone help me in solving the above issue?

Comment: I can confirm this error, but it is probably not from Tecplot. A recommendation is to downgrade it. I downgraded from `libcairo.so.2.11600.0` to `libcairo.so.2.11510.0` and it works (for whatever reasons)!